# HTML textarea coloring

Tags: html, css, colors

I'm trying to color my HTML `textarea` element with `CSS` and/or `JavaScript`, so it would show different colors when I type something in.

For example, if I typed in "Hello world," I might want it to be green because it is a string. Yet, I can't figure out how to do this.(Reminder: this is for typing in on a page, not in the pages source code)
I know it's possible because [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com) did it.

But, I can't just seem to find out how to color it. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default) is an example page from W3Schools. If you type something in, it will change color depending on what it is. I don't know how to make it do that though. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: You want to create a textarea that can change the color of specific keywords according to what they are. In other words, you want syntax highlighting?

Comment: @Spectric That's what I mean. I didn't know the words to use, though.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at [`highlist.js`](https://highlightjs.org/), as writing syntax highlighting yourself is generally not worth the time.

Comment: @Spectric Thank you for helping me! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using library like https://markjs.io because it would be too much time consuming to implement that from zero.

Here's an example of highlighting "found words"

```js
$(function() {
  var $input = $("input[name='keyword']"),
    $context = $("table tbody tr");
  $input.on("input", function() {
    var term = $(this).val();
    $context.show().unmark();
    if (term) {
      $context.mark(term, {
        done: function() {
          $context.not(":has(mark)").hide();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

More: https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/bs69vcqL/

Comment: Oh, my mistake, sorry. I've changed my answer to proper one.